# Spritekit : SKAction : timing

Tags: sprite-kit

I would like to know when you create a SKAction, you can define SKAction.timingMode and SKAction.timingFunction
both or you have to choose one of them only ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do neither, both, one, or the other.

For timingMode, the default value is linear.

For timingFunction, the default value is, well, nothing.

> If a timing function is provided, after the normal timing mode is applied, the result is sent to the timing function.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction